# Passing an argument to the index function in codeigniter controller giving error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using `codeigniter latest version`. I made some of the controllers and whenever i want to pass the argument through `URL` to `index()` function, it gives error message. But it works perfectly fine if the function is not `index()`. This is how i am trying to achieve this.

```
My URL:  localhost/ci_project/index/argument

class Index extends CI_Controller{

 public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
 }
 public function index($arg = null){
      echo $arg;                            // ERROR 404 Page not found
     $this->load->view('index',array('data'=>null));
 }
 public function other($arg = null){
    echo $arg;
    $this->load->view('other',array('data'=>null));

 }

}
```

This `URL: localhost/ci_project/other/argument` works perfectly fine but if i replace the controller `other` with `index` it gives an error message `404 Page not found`. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

The argument should be passed if the below link is clicked.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index/argument">Click to pass an argument</a>
```

Comment: how are you passing the argument? write the calling code please

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan... thanks for your reply. I have edited my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, echo your url like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index/argument">Click to pass an argument</a>
----------------------------------^
```

I just created a mock test with this Html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><a href="<?php echo base_url('tester'); ?>/index/argument">Click to pass an argument</a></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this php code:

```
class tester extends CI_Controller{

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

}

public function index($arg = 'null'){
    var_dump($arg);
    $this->load->view('tester');
  }
}
```

and the result was:

```
string(8) "argument"
Click to pass an argument
```

Comment: An additional question: can an index() function RETURN a value ?

Comment: Sure you can. It is a function at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Here your class name is index and the function name is too index, thus PHP thinks that your function index would be a constructor as the function name is same as the class name and thus you are experiencing the problem

Answer (score -1):

try

```
<?php echo base_url();?>/Index/index/argument
```

what i'm trying to say here, pass it as www.website.com/controller/function/argument